# Select field magento 2 Backend form

Tags: magento2, category-attribute, drop-downs

I have a category attribute that I have added to the admin view using...

```
 <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="category_customer_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">companyoptions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
```

This displays the form in the admin but with no options in the dropdown.

I then define the dataSource using

```
<dataSource name="companyoptions_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <!--<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">CompanyGridDataProvider</argument>-->

            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\CustomerProducts\Model\Config\Source\CompanyOptions</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">categry_company_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">companyId</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

In the Vendor\CustomerProducts\Model\Config\Source\CompanyOptions I have a getData() function which returns the data.... but the category page never loads....

Any help would be great.